# Calling a web service in .Net with an object as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, service-reference

I'm attempting to call a web service that requires some authentication although I'm slightly confused as to how I pass in the credentials for this authentication. The example SOAP request provided by the web service provider is as follows:

```
<s:Envelopexmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<h:ManagedUserHeaderxmlns:h="http://www.url.com/web/services/"xmlns="http://www.axumtech.com/web/services/"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<RegistrationKey>12345678910</RegistrationKey>
<CompanyName>TEST</CompanyName>
</h:ManagedUserHeader>
</s:Header>
<s:Bodyxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<GetContinentsxmlns="http://www.url.com/web/services/" />
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I will be consuming the web service using .Net in C#. I have done a few simple web service requests before but only ones where you pass in a simple string as part of the request to retrieve a response. I understand that for this request to work, I will have to pass in a ManagedUserHeader object that contains two properties, a registration key and a company name although whenever I try to program it in this way all I get are overload errors.

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;
using website.AxumStaticData;

namespace website.umbraco
{
  public partial class StaticDataService : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      StaticDataWebServiceSoapClient service = null;
      bool success = false;
      var guid = "12345678910";
      var companyName = "Test";
      var compressionSoapHeader = new AxumStaticData.CompressionSoapHeader();
      var managedUserHeader = new AxumStaticData.ManagedUserHeader();
      managedUserHeader.CompanyName = companyName;
      managedUserHeader.RegistrationKey = new Guid(guid);
      try{
          service = new StaticDataWebServiceSoapClient();
          var result = service.GetContinents(compressionSoapHeader,managedUserHeader);
      }finally{
          if (!success && service != null){
            service.Abort();
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the errors I receive in Visual Studio this line has some invalid arguments:

```
var result = service.GetContinents(compressionSoapHeader,managedUserHeader);
```

However, if I remove the parameters, I get the following error:

```
No overload for method 'GetContinents' takes 0 arguments
```

I'm really struggling with this as I've only ever called web services in pure XML before so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide more information if required.

Comment: What is needed in GetContinents()?

Comment: @sr28 According to Visual Studio is requires two parameters although I know the first is optional: ContinentData[]StaticDataWebServiceSoapClient.GetContinents(ref CompressionSoapHeader CompressionSoapHeader, ref ManagedUserHeader ManagedUserHeader)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = service.GetContinents(ref compressionSoapHeader, ref managedUserHeader);
```

When the method has a `ref` parameter, you need to include `ref`. When it has an `out` parameter, you need to include `out`.

Comment: This doesn't work as I should then be able to do a for each(var response in result){var something = response.Id}) but visual studio suggests that those options are not available meaning it's not working correctly.

Comment: Seriously, go look at the types of the parameters. Do you not know how to use the Object Browser to look at types? See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: I've already done that and I'm learning so cut me some slack.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the end was due to the compression soap header object requiring a compression method to be specified. I had tried this before but the compression method is of type enum so I had to do the following:

```
var compressionSoapHeader = new CompressionSoapHeader();
compressionSoapHeader.CompressionMethodUsed = CompressionMethods.None;
```

After all of that, my web service request completed successfully.